# How to add directory to PATH on kaggle?

Tags: path, kaggle

How to add directory to PATH on kaggle ?

Standard way (see e.g. [discussion here](http://discussion%20here) )
!export PATH=/root/edirect/:$PATH

does not work

See example:
https://www.kaggle.com/alexandervc/entrezdirect?scriptVersionId=70892045&cellId=17

It might be that "t looks like each command in that pipe is being executed in a separate shell and that is why you are losing the $PATH setting for those sub shells." as [proposed here](https://www.biostars.org/p/9483310/#9483333). That would possibly imply that it is impossible to do something with that issue.

PS
More generally I am trying to use EntrezDirect on kaggle, see the first answer here:
https://www.biostars.org/p/9483310/#9483333

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (thanks to Leigh.plt from ODS ) :

> os.environ['PATH'] = "/kaggle/working:" + os.environ['PATH']

Notebook:

https://www.kaggle.com/alexandervc/path-trick-to-change-on-kaggle?scriptVersionId=71644458

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't the PATH be updated using:

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("path/to/be/added/"))

Comment: Does not work either https://www.kaggle.com/alexandervc/path-fail-to-change?scriptVersionId=71541003